# Accessing Returned Javascript Variable in another Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, scope

I've got script (a) that is a javascript script in which I've go this function:

```
function csf_viewport_bounds() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

    var maxLat = ne.lat();
    var maxLong = ne.lng();
    var minLat = sw.lat();
    var minLong = sw.lng();

    var the_maps_bounds = [maxLat, maxLong, minLat, minLong];

    return(the_maps_bounds);
 }
```

I've also got jQuery script (b). It has a line that calls the function in (a):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded',  csf_viewport_bounds);
```

How can I access the what is returned by (a), the_maps_bounds, in script (b)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you want to do something after `tilesloaded` that involves `the_maps_bounds` in which case you would do something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded',  function() {
    // This code will only execute after event `tilesloaded` happens

    var the_maps_bounds = csf_viewport_bounds()

    // now do something with the bounds
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function a second time, since it doesn't use any parameters, and assign the result to a variable.

```
var myStuff = csf_viewport_bounds()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change script (b) to:

```
var bounds = csf_viewport_bounds();
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', bounds);
// csf_viewport_bounds() return saved as local variable bounds.
```